# @NamedNativeQuery @SqlResultSetMapping wrong mapping COUNT(*)

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-native-query

I'm having a strange error using @SqlResultSetMapping and @NamedNativeQuery.

My Entity has:

```
@NamedNativeQuery(
        name = "example_query",
        query = "SELECT table_A.id, " +
                "COUNT(*) AS numberOfA " +
                "FROM table_A table_A " +
                "  JOIN example example ON example.id = :idExample " +
                "GROUP BY id " +
                "ORDER BY numberOfA DESC;",
        resultSetMapping = "myMapping"
)
@SqlResultSetMapping(
        name = "myMapping",
        classes = @ConstructorResult(
                targetClass = ExampleDTO.class,
                columns = {
                        @ColumnResult(name = "id", type = Integer.class),
                        @ColumnResult(name = "numberOfA", type = Integer.class)
                }
        )
)
public class Entity implements Serializable { /////// }
```

My DTO is like:

```
public class ExampleDTO {

    private Integer id;
    private Integer numberOfA;

}
```

My Repository:

```
public interface Entity extends JpaRepository<Entity,Integer> {

    @Query(name = "example_query", nativeQuery = true)
    List<ExampleDTO> findExampleQuery(@Param("id") Integer id);

}
```

On the database the same query return:

```
id     |      numberofa
 1               11
 2                5
```

and the mapping return an object with:

```
id     |      numberofa
 1               154
 2                70
```

How is that possible?

Comment: How does the executed SQL statement look like?

Comment: And the join looks wired: "FROM table_A table_A JOIN example example ON example.id = :idExample " you are not joing table_A and example at all

Answer (score 0):

You should create DTO is an entity and ensure that values of query which map to id field (one or more) in DTO are not duplicated

My DTO:

```
@Embeddable
public class PrimaryKey implements Serializable {
    private int job_id;
    private int prof_id;
}



@SqlResultSetMapping(
        name = "JobProfileResultMapping",
        classes = @ConstructorResult(
                targetClass = JobProfileResult.class,
                columns = {
                        @ColumnResult(name = "job_id", type = Integer.class),
                        @ColumnResult(name = "prof_id", type = Integer.class),
                        @ColumnResult(name = "title", type = String.class),
                        @ColumnResult(name = "name", type = String.class)
                }
        )
)
@Entity
@IdClass(PrimaryKey.class)
public class JobProfileResult {
    @Id
    private int job_id;

    @Id
    private int prof_id;
    private String title;

    private String name;

    public void setJob_id(int job_id) {
        this.job_id = job_id;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getJob_id() {
        return job_id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

My repository:

```
@Repository
public interface JobProfileRepository extends JpaRepository<JobProfileResult, Integer> {
    @Query(value = "select j.job_id, p.prof_id, j.title, p.name from job j join job_profile jp on j.job_id=jp.job_id join profile p on jp.prof_id=p.prof_id", nativeQuery = true)
    public List<JobProfileResult> getJobProfile();
}
```